# Says on the iceConnectionState that is connected but does not run the onaddstream function

Tags: javascript, react-native, webrtc

I have a code like that that runs the ice connection state change and says that the `this.pc.iceConnectionState` is completed but the function
`this.pc.onaddstream` never runs

I've tried refactoring the code and spliting in two components but i got the same behaviour

```
this.pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
  console.log('ICE STATE', this.pc.iceConnectionState);
  if (
    this.pc.iceConnectionState === 'failed' ||
    this.pc.iceConnectionState === 'disconnected' ||
    this.pc.iceConnectionState === 'closed'
  ) {
    console.log('Failed');
  } else if (this.pc.iceConnectionState === 'checking') {
    console.log('Checking');
  } else {
    this.setState({
      success: true,
    });
    console.log('Success');
  }
};

this.pc.onaddstream = e => {
  console.log('Stream event', e);
}
```

The expected result is to log the stream event when the event is completed.

Comment: You're showing us the code that is working. What media, if any, have you added?

Answer (score 0):

onAddStream has been depreciated. Use onTrack instead.